# read docx document using java

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I have a project steganography to hide `docx` document into `jpeg` image. Using apache POI, I can run it and read `docx` document but only letters can be read.

Even though there are pictures in it.

Here is the code

```
FileInputStream in = null;
    try
    {
        in = new FileInputStream(directory);
        XWPFDocument datax = new XWPFDocument(in);
        XWPFWordExtractor extract = new XWPFWordExtractor(datax);
        String DataFinal = extract.getText();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = null;
        this.isi_file = extract.getText();
    }
    catch (IOException x) {}
        System.out.println("isi :" + this.isi_file);
```

How can I read all component in the docx document using java? Please help me and thank you for your helping.

Comment: A docx file, like any other file is a bunch of bytes. When read by the appropriate decoder then you can view the text and images properly. But in terms of hiding the file, just read the file in a byte array.

Comment: how about the code?

Comment: What code? To do what I suggested? It's been covered before. Search for how to read a file to a byte array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html) for `XWPFDocument` class. It contains some useful methods, for example:

- [`getAllPictures()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#getAllPictures--) returns list of all pictures in document;
- [`getTables()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#getTables--) returns list of all tables in document.

In your code snippet exists line `XWPFDocument datax = new XWPFDocument(in);`. So after that line your can write some code like:

```
// process all pictures in document
for (XWPFPictureData picture : datax.getAllPictures()) {
    // get each picture as byte array
    byte[] pictureData = picture.getData();
    // process picture somehow
    ...
}
```

Comment: How can I make it be the code? I dont get the meaning in that documentation.

Comment: @Apuranic, I edit my answer and add small code snippet that shows how to process pictures in document. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Apuranic, output of what? Please provide concrete code snippet, because my example is incomplete and even would not compile without your modifications.

Comment: oh I see, sorry for misunderstanding n thank you for your help :)